# Is this flyweight pattern really a flyweight pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Here's a tutorial I was reading:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/flyweight_pattern.htm

Here's the code I think is not a flyweight pattern as stated:

```
public interface Shape {
   void draw();
}

public class Circle implements Shape {
   private String color;
   private int x;
   private int y;
   private int radius;

   public Circle(String color){
      this.color = color;       
   }

   public void setX(int x) {
      this.x = x;
   }

   public void setY(int y) {
      this.y = y;
   }

   public void setRadius(int radius) {
      this.radius = radius;
   }

   @Override
   public void draw() {
      System.out.println("Circle: Draw() [Color : " + color + ", x : " + x + ", y :" + y + ", radius :" + radius);
   }
}

import java.util.HashMap;

public class ShapeFactory {
   private static final HashMap<String, Shape> circleMap = new HashMap();

   public static Shape getCircle(String color) {
      Circle circle = (Circle)circleMap.get(color);

      if(circle == null) {
         circle = new Circle(color);
         circleMap.put(color, circle);
         System.out.println("Creating circle of color : " + color);
      }
      return circle;
   }
}

public class FlyweightPatternDemo {
   private static final String colors[] = { "Red", "Green", "Blue", "White", "Black" };
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      for(int i=0; i < 20; ++i) {
         Circle circle = (Circle)ShapeFactory.getCircle(getRandomColor());
         circle.setX(getRandomX());
         circle.setY(getRandomY());
         circle.setRadius(100);
         circle.draw();
      }
   }
   private static String getRandomColor() {
      return colors[(int)(Math.random()*colors.length)];
   }
   private static int getRandomX() {
      return (int)(Math.random()*100 );
   }
   private static int getRandomY() {
      return (int)(Math.random()*100);
   }
}
```

This doesn't seem me a flyweight pattern because according to wikipedia "A flyweight is an object that minimizes memory use by sharing as much data as possible with other similar objects". In other words, I cannot see an object with intrinsic and extrinsic data. Here I can only see a factory with some sort of caching system.

Can someone demonstrate why this is or is not a flyweight pattern?

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question instead of linking to it

Comment: added the relevant code

Comment: I think if colour was another class and the factory was caching colours instead of shapes, then it would be flyweight.

Comment: @user1883212 Geeze, that's what I *thought* was happening. However it 'makes sense' in the context that the shape itself is being cached as the Circle is only used in the *immediate* scope (when it draws itself). So *no circles are actually being 'shared'* to another context as there is only one instance ever in use. (It would be bad if they *were* shared because of the mutable state.)

Comment: Your confusion is totally understandable. This code is clearly trying to demonstrate Flyweight, but it's buggy (and makes no sense IMHO) and the tutorial is poorly written. (Other tutorials on that site look similar.) I'd find a different resource, like the [original GoF Design Patterns book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) or [Design Patterns in Java](http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Java-TM-Software/dp/0321333020/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1432501949&sr=8-1&keywords=Design+patterns+in+Java).

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) is also clearer. Ultimately a flyweight is simply a type of caching though, so the *gist* of your article is right - it's a factory with caching.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new circle through the `ShapeFactory` an already created instance is returned, in case one exists for the desired color. This way you can reuse your created instances of `Circle` (they "share" their data with circles with the same color) and minimize memory consumption.

That said, this code exhibits some problems. Fore example, the `Circle` objects are mutable so if you start modifying a created circle, all other circles of the same color will also be modified.

And it is utterly thread-unsafe.